# R nlminb What does false convergence actually mean?

Tags: r, optimization, fortran

I'm using the function nlminb to maximise a function and got convergence (convergence =0 ) with the message false-convergence.

I tried the documentation but no answer. I tried to get the [port documentation](http://www.netlib.org/port/) on the function and could find the function `nlminb`

Can anyone point me to the port documentation of `nlminb` or explain what does false convergence mean please ?

I also tried other optimization function but though nlminb is a bit obscure, it seems to converge faster than any other function to the right answer. Need to perform more test to make sure. Even using the `nlminb` through optimx is considerably slow.

It would be a good thing if we understand more how this function work. Fortran coders feel free to help please.

**Edit**
I should have found the code earlier. [Here](https://github.com/DJJ88/R-3.3.1/blob/master/src/library/stats/src/port.c) it is but it is still obscure. Can somebody help

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a repost/adaptation of an [answer of mine from r-sig-mixed models](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2013q1/019968.html)

[... The nlminb() optimizer ... is based on the PORT libraries.

The docs linked from `?nlminb` *used to be* at `http://netlib.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cstr/153.pdf`: http://www.netlib.org/port/cs/cstr says

> port/readme points to "Usage Summary for Selected Optimization Routines", sometimes known as PORT OPTIMIZATION DOCUMENTATION in http://netlib.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cstr/153.ps.gz or http://netlib.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cstr/153.pdf

... but these links are broken (`port/readme` is still there but none of the links provided work ...).

I managed to find the docs via [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&q=author%3Agay+usage+summary+for+selected+optimization+routines) and have posted a slightly more convenient [PDF version](http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/misc/port.pdf).

The only useful material I could find in these docs was:

> p. 5: false convergence: the gradient ∇f(x) may be computed
>   incorrectly, the other stopping tolerances may be too tight, or either
>   f or ∇f may be discontinuous near the current iterate x.
>
> p. 9: V(XFTOL) — V(34) is the false-convergence tolerance. A return
>   with IV(1) = 8 occurs if a more favorable stopping test is not
>   satisfied and if a step of scaled length at most V(XFTOL) is tried but
>   not accepted. ‘‘Scaled length’’ is in the sense of (5.1). Such a
>   return generally means there is an error in computing ∇f(x), or
>   the favorable convergence tolerances (V(RFCTOL), V(XCTOL), and
>   perhaps V(AFCTOL)) are too tight for the accuracy to which f(x) is
>   computed (see §9), or ∇f (or f itself) is discontinuous near x . An
>   error in computing ∇f(x) usually leads to false convergence after
>   only a few iterations — often in the first.  Default = 100*MACHEP.
>
> p. 13: Sometimes evaluating f(x) involves an extensive computation,
>   such as performing a simulation or adaptive numerical quadrature or
>   integrating an ordinary or partial differential equation. In such
>   cases the value computed for f (x), say f̃( x ), may involve
>   substantial error (in the eyes of the optimization algorithm).  To
>   eliminate some ‘‘false convergence’’ messages and useless function
>   evaluations, it is necessary to increase the stopping tolerances and,
>   when finite-difference derivative approximations are used, to increase
>   the step-sizes used in estimating derivatives.

Comment: Many thanks for this detailed explanation. I think this post provide valuable information about nlminb that are not easily to find if you don't know where to look. It was not on SO as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'm using analytical gradient and hessian that I think I have well tested. Therefore I looking a the  stopping tolerance.