# Understanding and fixing false convergence errors in glmmTMB + lme4

Tags: r, lme4, glmmtmb

I am trying to use `glmmTMB` to run a number of iterations of my model, but keep getting the same continual error. I have tried to explain my experiment below and inserted the full model I am trying to run.

### Background to the experiment

The dependent variable I am trying to model is bacterial 16S gene copy number, used as a proxy for bacterial biomass in this case.

The experimental design is that I have stream sediment from 8 streams that fall along a pollution gradient (impacted to pristine). (Factor 1 = Stream, with 8 levels).

For each of the 8 streams, the following was performed,
Sediment was added to 6 trays. 3 of these trays were placed into an artificial stream channel warmed to 13°C, whilst the other 3 were heated to 17°C (Factor 2 = Warming treatment, with 2 levels). There are 16 channels in total and Warming treatment was randomly assigned to a channel.

I then repeatedly measured the 3 trays in each stream channel over four time points (Factor 3 = Day, with 4 levels).

At this moment in time I am treating tray as a true biological replicate and not a pseudorep as the trays are considerably far away from one another in the channels, but this is to be explored.

So just to summarise: the model terms are (all are specified as factors):

- Warming treatment (13 vs 17oC)
- StreamID (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
- Day (T1, T4, T7, T14)

The full model I was proposing was,

```
X4_tmb.nb2<-glmmTMB(CopyNo~Treatment*Stream*Time, family=nbinom2, data=qPCR)
```

Even though this version of the model does not include a random effect, I wanted to use the `glmmTMB` package and not run this using `lme4`, because I wanted to explore the idea of adding a model component to account for dispersion, and also explore the option of adding tray as a random effect (not sure if this is correct). By running all versions of the model in `glmmTMB`, I am able to confidently compare their AIC scores. I wouldn't be able to do this if I ran the full model without the dispersion component in `lme4` and the others using `glmmTMB`.

Unfortunately, for most iterations of the full model when using glmmTMB (by this I mean dropping model terms sequentially), I get the same constant warning:

> Warning message: In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
>     Model convergence problem; false convergence (8). See vignette('troubleshooting')

I have tried to understand the error but I am struggling to understand because, the confusing thing is when I run the full model using lme4, it runs with no error.

This is the version of the full model that runs in lme4,

```
X4 = glm.nb(CopyNo~Treatment*Stream*Time, data = qPCR
```

As far as I understand from reading https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/132753v1.full.pdf
@ line 225, it is possible to use this package to cross compare between GLMs and GLMMs. Do you know if I have understood this correctly?

I also used the `DHARMa` package to help validate the models and the version that failed to converge using `glmmTMB`, pass the KStest, the dispersion test, the outlier test and combined adjusted quantile test, but ideally I do not want the convergence error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing the optimizer in `glmmTMB()`?  That is often my first go-to for convergence issues (and it looks like that's one of the things mentioned in the "false convergence" section of the [glmmTMB troubleshooting vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/troubleshooting.html) :) ).

Answer (score 4):

There's a bunch here.

### warning message

It is unfortunately hard to do very much about this: it is a [notoriously obscure error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039114/r-nlminb-what-does-false-convergence-actually-mean). As [suggested on twitter](https://twitter.com/microbeEcology/status/1274095974873513988), you can try a different optimizer, e.g. include

```
 control = glmmTMBControl(optimizer = optim, optArgs = list(method="BFGS"))
```

in your call.  Hopefully this will give a very similar answer (in which case you conclude that the convergence warning was probably a false positive, as different optimizers are unlikely to fail in the same way) without the warning. (You could try `method="CG"` above as a third alternative.) (Note that there's a minor bug with printing and summarizing output when using alternate optimizers that was [fixed recently](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/commit/914d63e7b0a6060bda1621317e1889b337d5eca3); you might want to install the development version if you are working on this before the fix propagates to CRAN.)

### "lme4" model

The `glm.nb()` function is *not* from the `lme4` package, it's from the `MASS` package. If you had random effects in the model you would use `glmer.nb()`, which *is* in the `lme4` package ... as with the optimizer-switching tests above, if you get similar answers with `glmmTMB` and `glm.nb` you can conclude that the warning from `glmmTMB` (actually, it's from the `nlminb()` optimizer that `glmmTMB` calls internally) is probably a false positive.

The simplest way to check that likelihoods/AICs from different packages are commensurate is to fit the same model in both packages, if possible, e.g.

```
library(MASS)
library(glmmTMB)

quine.nb1 <- glm.nb(Days ~ Sex/(Age + Eth*Lrn), data = quine)
quine.nb2 <- glmmTMB(Days ~ Sex/(Age + Eth*Lrn), data = quine,
                     family=nbinom2)
all.equal(AIC(quine.nb1),AIC(quine.nb2))  ## TRUE
```

### other details

One of the possible problems with your model is that by fitting the full three-way interaction of three categorical variables you're trying to estimate (2*4*8=) 64 parameters, to 64*3=192 observations (if I understand your experimental design correctly). This is both more likely to run into numerical problems (as above) and may give imprecise results. Although some recommend it, I **do not** personally recommend a model selection approach (all-subsets or sequential, AIC-based or p-value-based); I'd suggest making Stream into a random effect, i.e.

```
CopyNo ~ Treatment + (Treatment|StreamID) + (1|Time/StreamID)
```

This fits (1) an overall treatment effect; (2) variation across streams, variation in treatment effect across streams; (3) variation across time and across streams within time points. This only uses 2 (fixed: intercept + treatment) + 3 (intercept variance, treatment variance, and their covariance across streams) + 2 (variance in time and among streams within time).  This is not quite the "maximal" model; since both treatments are measured at each time in each stream, the last term could be (Treatment|Time/StreamID), but this would add a lot of model complexity. Since 4 groups is not much for a random effect, you might find that you want to make the last term into `Time + (1|Time:StreamID)`, which will fit Time as fixed and (streams within time) as random ...

Comment: Thank you for all of the comments. I really do appreciate you taking the time for what is probably a simple problem. My confusion with between lme4 and MASS was a silly error, I just got muddled up, but I thank you for the all.equal tip. This is great to know!                     
I will attempt your suggestions and let you know how I get on. I feel you have rally helped my understanding and hopefully I can move forward. Many thanks!